# Indian Tortoise all puffy

Tags: health, diseases, tortoises, eye-disease

We have two baby tortoise (twins - from the same egg).

Recently we went on holiday for Christmas and left both Elmo and Leon at a pet boarding (which had good reviews). When we came back yesterday Elmo looked very weak and puffy, he didn't opened his eyes at all. The vivarium in which they were kept was soaking wet.

Since yesterday Elmo has barely been moving, he refuses food, he doesn't react much when you touch him, and his eyes are closed. We have given him 2 hot baths yesterday and one this morning, but not much reaction.

We have an emergency vet appointment later on today, but unfortunately we couldn't get a reptile vet appointment.

If any of you has been in a similar case, or know how we can help our tiny Elmo, that'd be highly appreciated.

I have added pictures, before (eyes opened -- less puffy) and after (eyes closed).

[image: Elmo Healthy]
[image: Elmo all puffy]

Comment: My best guess is that it's an infection of some kind, maybe treated by antibiotics?  I don't have direct tortoise experience, though, I have a turtle.

Comment: Meg, we have now been to the vet, Elmo is indeed under an antibiotic treatment. Unfortunately there is still a lot of uncertainties about this tiny monster.

Comment: It's hard to find a good vet with reptile experience, or much good information about it online.  Wishing the best for your little Elmo's recovery.

Comment: a lots of dog-cat-vets have no experience with turtles or tortoises. For example should they never give injections into the back legs, except it is for treatment of the kidney. Most reptile- unexperienced vets give antibiotics and vitamin injections to treat everything they do not know. You could test them if you call and ask for a blood test. The most do not dare to get blood from a turtle/tortoise if they are not reptile experienced.

Answer (score 1):

You need an adequate heat or UV light for the tortoise's vivarium. Improper set up can lead to indigestion of food. Too much humidity is not good and an unsafe environment can also lead them to not move or eat.

Comment: I agree with this point, but some sources would be great... Minimum to have a point from which one could research further